# How to take part from input numbers?

Tags: java, android

Sorry still learning and new to code. I don’t know if the title is clear or not, I'm trying to get user last and first input digits, I followed some tutorial and changed it to what I need the problem is I get some numbers even if the Edit Text is empty. I don't know if there is another way or not I just followed some topic to get first and last digit. Here is my code .

```
EditText ca_code = findViewById(R.id.caps_code);
TextView txt_code_out = findViewById(R.id.out_code);
int mutli = 0;

String lst_code = String.valueOf(ca_code);
//char fst = lst_code.charAt(0);
//char snd = lst_code.charAt(1);
char lat = lst_code.charAt(lst_code.length() - 1);
txt_code_out.setText(String.valueOf((int) lat));
```

for this i get different output if i change `length() - 1` 
for `-1 = output = 125` and for `-2 =101 , -3=100, -4= 111, -5 =99`

**Then I changed the code little bit to**

```
EditText capscode = findViewById(R.id.caps_code);
TextView txt_code_out = findViewById(R.id.out_code);

String lst_code = String.valueOf(capscode);
//char fst = lst_code.charAt(0);
//char snd = lst_code.charAt(1);
char lat = lst_code.charAt(lst_code.length() - 1);
txt_code_out.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
```

The output was `}edoc_spac/di:ppa 7 300,,,` for -1 to 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to:

```
String lst_code = capscode.getText().toString();
```

`capscode` is an `EditText` not a number or a `String`.
With `getText().toString()` you don't need `String.valueOf()`.

Comment: oh thanks was editing a lot i tried with this didint work 'double lst_code = Double.parseDouble(capscode.getText().toString());' but yours work now ty u so much for the first and 2nd digit  just charAt(0) and charAt(1)?

Comment: Thank u so much :).

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
String lst_code = String.valueOf(capscode);
```

to

```
String lst_code = capscode.getText().toString();
```

The variable `capscode` is of type `EditText`, which has a method `getText()` to retrieve its current value. The value is from type `Editable` again and it provides a `toString()` method finally.

Comment: ya thank u so much was trying with different way. it work ;)